# create dynamic navigation from xml file in flash cs3

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I want to hand an xml file to a swf and have the swf generate a dynamic text box and button for each of the links in the xml file

a rudimentary navigation

here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <page>
    <page name="Page Name 1" url="/page-1/" />
    <page name="Page Name 2" url="/page-2/" />
    <page name="Page Name 3" url="/page-3/" />
    <page name="Page Name 4" url="/page-4/" />
    </page>
```

and in my fla I have a button in my library named 'nav_button'

there's a layer named actions and in frame 1 I have this

```
var xml:XML;
var xmlList:XMLList;
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

var button:Button = new Button();


xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("links.xml"));

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{
xml = XML(event.target.data);
xmlList = xml.children();
trace(xml.length());

for(var i:int = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i++)
{
    button = new Button();
    button.x = 25;
    button.y = i * 50 +25; 
    addChild(button);
}
}
```

the xml imports fine, but when it comes to the for loop and adding the buttons and text boxes to the stage, I'm toast

Comment: oops. fixed the xml file @Kristof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml file is invalid. It can only contain a single root node.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pages>
<page name="Page Name 1" url="/page-1/" />
<page name="Page Name 2" url="/page-2/" />
<page name="Page Name 3" url="/page-3/" />
<page name="Page Name 4" url="/page-4/" />
</pages>
```

This is the code for your first frame:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("links.xml"));

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void {
    var pages:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
    var i:int = 0;
    for each (var page:XML in pages.page) {
        var button:LinkButton = new LinkButton();
        button.x = 25;
        button.y = i * 50 + 25; 
        button.label = page.attribute("name");
        button.url = page.attribute("url");
        addChild(button);
        trace(i++);
    }
}
```

And you'll need a custom button class:

```
package {
    import fl.controls.Button;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;

    public class LinkButton extends fl.controls.Button {
        public var url:String;
        public function LinkButton(){
            super();
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        }
        private function clickHandler(mouseEvent:MouseEvent) {
            flash.net.navigateToURL(new URLRequest(url), "_blank");
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I need to explain this in a bit more detail:

1. create a new Flash File (<kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd>)
2. open the Components panel (<kbd>Ctrl-F7</kbd>)
3. open the Library panel (<kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd>)
4. drag Components > User Interface > Button to Library
5. Select the first frame
6. open the actions panel (<kbd>F9</kbd>)
7. paste the first bit of code here
8. Save your file (<kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>)
9. create a new ActionScript File (<kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd>)
10. paste the second bit of code here
11. Save your file in the same folder as "LinkButton.as" (<kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>)
12. Go back to your Movie (<kbd>Ctrl-Tab</kbd>)
13. test the movie (<kbd>Ctrl-Enter</kbd>)

I strongly recommend you take some more training. [Lee Brimelows site](http://www.gotoandlearn.com) is a good place to start.

Comment: ok, I pasted all of the code in frame 1 on the actions layer

got the eror "1083: Syntax error: package is unexpected."

does the package need to be put somewhere else?

Comment: the entire LinkButton class (everything from "package" to the end)needs  to be placed in an external .as file. you can create this in CS3 by going to File -> New -> ActionScript File.

Comment: I think I've got the class file moved..now I'm getting these errors

1017: The definition of base class Button was not found.
5000: The class 'customButtons' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.

Comment: Wow! It works. Thank you so much. I'm sorry I needed such basic instruction. I tried working through a couple tutorials to get as far as I could, but I agree that I definitely need some more training. I'll be bookmarking the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, but it was new to me today.

I don't understand why you'd want to create a custom button class. I don't think it's necessary to accomplish what you were trying to do.

```
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void {
    var pages:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
    var i:int = 0;
    for each (var page:XML in pages.page) {
        var button:LinkButton = new LinkButton();
        button.x = 25;
        button.y = i * 50 + 25; 
        button.label = page.attribute("name");
        button.url = page.attribute("url");
        addChild(button);
        trace(i++);
    }
}
```

The function above is fine as far as it goes, but why not add the event listener in the for loop?  Add the line:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoURL);
```

within the for loop, then add the function:

```
function gotoURL(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(e.target.url));
}
```

This would eliminate the need for creating external files and custom classes.

Comment: thanks Sam helped me out a lot wih this reply for a problem i was having :)