# flash as3 generating dynamic buttons from xml and referencing associated data on click

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, button, onclick

Hi ther am having problems with my flash code.
I think i am just a tad out of my depth so any help would be appreciated.

I have an xml file with the following structure:

```
<buttons>
    <button>
        <id>Garden</id>
        <xPos>99</xPos>
        <yPos>364</yPos>
        <content>
        <![CDATA[
<h1>Walls</h1>here is information on Garden's will go here<br> enter any information you like and it will be displayed in the information panel.<br>here is a example product link: <a href="http://coccosrl.dizzyhigh.com/category/prodotti/">tutti prodotti</a><br>and here is another<a href="http://coccosrl.dizzyhigh.com/prodotti/bordi-battentati/">bordi-battentati</a><br>
        ]]>
        </content>
    </button>
    <button>
        ..................
    </button>
</buttons>
```

I want to load this data into flash, and have the buttons display on the screen at the appropriate x/y co-ords. 
When a button is clicked to display the info from the content node for the associated button.

however i am having problems getting the data for the content node to trace to the output window.

how do i go about referencing the content node from the xml for the associated button?

frame1 Code:

```
stop();
import myGlobal;

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showXML);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("buttons.xml"));
function showXML(e:Event):void {
    XML.ignoreWhitespace = true; 
    myGlobal.buttonData = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myGlobal.buttonData.button.length());
    gotoAndStop("main");
}
```

frame 2 Code (main):

```
stop();    
var i:Number;
    for (i=0; i < myGlobal.buttonData.button.length(); i++) {
        trace(" name of button: "+ myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].title.text());
        trace(" xPos: "+ myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].xPos.text());
        trace(" yPos: "+ myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].yPos.text());
        trace(" yPos: "+ myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].content.text());
        //add button to stage
        this[myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].title.text()] = new iBtn(); 
        this[myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].title.text()].y = myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].yPos.text();
        this[myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].title.text()].x = myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].xPos.text();

        addChild(this[myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].title.text()])
        this[myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].title.text()].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
    }
    function btnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //do all the stuff i want to happen when a button is clicked here....
            trace(e.target.id);
    }
```

i am using a myGlobal.as file as a holder for all my data so i can access it across the whole fla:

```
package {
    public class myGlobal {
        public static var buttonData:XML;
        public static var panelStatus:Boolean = new Boolean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found part of the answer in this thread:
[create dynamic navigation from xml file in flash cs3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806864/create-dynamic-navigation-from-xml-file-in-flash-cs3)

what i have done is to have in my code for generating the button:

```
this[myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].title.text()].myContent = myGlobal.buttonData.button[i].content.text();
```

then in the click function:

```
function btnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace(e.target.myContent);
    Object(root).infoPanel.panelClip.infoText.htmlText = e.target.myContent;
    if(myGlobal.panelStatus == false){
        Object(this).infoPanel.gotoAndPlay("show");
    }   
};
```

I hadn't realised i could add attach extra info to a button, is much cleaner than having to look up a reference to the xml each time.